CiviCRM Wordpress Critical Error Upon Event Registration
When registering for an event - I get the following fatal error:
Registration is successful, email is sent.
Thank You page is not displayed.
CiviCRM 5.73.3 WordPress 6.5.4
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\PCPBlock' not found in /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/ThankYou.php:227 Stack trace: #0 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/ThankYou.php(193): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_ThankYou->getPCPBlockID() #1 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(774): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_ThankYou->buildQuickForm() #2 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm() #3 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_ThankYou), 'display') #4 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_ThankYou), 'display') #5 /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content in /home/prinyc/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/ThankYou.php on line 227



It sounds like you don't have civicontribute enabled.

I don't, do we need it? we don't accept contributions.

Enabled civicontribute and that solved it - strange. Thanks for the tip
